# When type is []byte, it fails at case statement in golang

Tags: go, case, reflect

```
func Test(val any) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(val) {
    case nil://ok
    case string://ok
    case []byte://error here,expected expression
    }
}
```

As the code above, I am trying to make some statement according to the type of input value. However it  fails to pass the grammer check when the type of input value is `[]byte`.  How to fix this
problem?

I found an example and I think is what I need:

```
    switch v.(type) {
    case *string:
    case *[]byte:
    case *int:
    case *bool:
    case *float32:
    case *[]string:
    case *map[string]string:
    case *map[string]interface{}:
    case *time.Duration:
    case *time.Time:
    }
```

Comment: That's an **expression** switch not a **type** switch, **do NOT feed types to expression switch cases**. `case string:` can be ok ONLY if you have overwritten the predeclared type identifier by declaring a variable with the same name. See https://go.dev/play/p/iVusyyiyhWK, `string` is NOT an expression (unless you've declared a variable with that name).

Answer (score 1):

`reflect.TypeOf()` returns an object of the interface [`Type`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type), which isn't implemented by `[]byte` (or `string`).

You can go that route to switch betwen types (taken from https://go.dev/tour/methods/16):

```
func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v*2)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v))
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }
}
```

If you don't need `v`,  `switch i.(type)` is also fine.

Comment: The prbolem is not i.(type) nor reflect.TypeOf(i),  the problem is ```case []byte``` is not correct. I realy want to know how to deal with the case when type is ```[]byte```

Comment: @tanxin `[]byte` is not a possible implementation of the `Type` interface (that you get from `reflect.TypeOf()`). Neither is `string` (and my compiler complains about that one, too).

Comment: I edited my question by adding an example.

Comment: Your example equals my one. It's a type switch, as suggested. The only difference is that your example reads `switch v.(type`) while mine was `switch i.(type)`, so it's basically just different naming. Additionally, your example isn't really related to your question.